# How to define a variable inside the print function?

Tags: python, syntax

I am a newbie in this field, and I am trying to solve a problem (not really sure if it is possible actually) where I want to print on the display some information plus some input from the user.

The following works fine:

```
>>> print (" Hello " + input("tellmeyourname: "))
tellmeyourname: dfsdf
 Hello dfsdf
```

However if I want to assign user's input to a variable, I can't:

```
>>> print (" Hello ", name = input("tellmeyourname: "))
tellmeyourname: mike
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#47>", line 1, in <module>
    print (" Hello ", name = input("tellmeyourname: "))
TypeError: 'name' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

I have researched inside here and other python documentation, tried with `%s` etc. to solve, without result. I don't want to use it in two lines (first assigning the variable `name= input("tellmeyourname:")` and then printing). 
Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you need to achieve this?

Comment: Specifically, why don't you just use two statements?  What possible reason is there to want to do this in one line?

Comment: "I don't want to use it in two lines" - why not? Sticking the assignment inside the print is a lot more error-prone and less reasonable, which is why Python doesn't let you do it.

Comment: you cannot put the assignment inside the print so the why is pretty much irrelevant

Comment: thanks everyone for the VERY prompt answers! didn't expect that. Basically that was a question of one of my students, and I assume she wanted to write efficient code.

Comment: What gave you, or your student, the impression that a) this syntax would assign the input to `name` or b) be more efficient than simply using two lines?  The number of lines has nothing to do with the efficiency of the program.

Comment: perhaps he misspoke and meant DRY (which having 2 lines does not prevent in any way :) )

Comment: We are both new in the field, and she insisted of knowing a way to actually complete this in one line. I thought, well maybe there is a way and simply I don't know it. So I researched, found nothing, and here I am..Thanks again!

Comment: in some languages an assignment does return a value (usually the right side of the = ) .... however python does not....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting from Python 3.8, this will become possible using an [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/):

```
print("Your name is: " + (name := input("Tell me your name: ")))
print("Your name is still: " + name)
```

Though 'possible' is not the same as 'advisable'...

---

But in Python <3.8: you can't. Instead, separate your code into two statements:

```
name = input("Tell me your name: ")
print("Your name is: " + name)
```

If you often find yourself wanting to use two lines like this, you could make it into a function:

```
def input_and_print(question):
  s = input("{} ".format(question))
  print("You entered: {}".format(s))

input_and_print("What is your name?")
```

Additionally you could have the function return the input `s`.

Comment: while this is correct Im not sure it answers the question of the OP ... +1 all the same because its correct

Comment: Well, the only other thing I can mention is that it can't be done in one statement.

Comment: and that is the OP's question ... he clearly indicates in the question he knows he can do it as two statements(and correctly you advise him to), but his question was "can I do this thing?" the answer is no (note I still upvoted you because I clearly agree with you)

Comment: amazed at how many more upvotes this has gotten than my solution (its a good solution I agree :) )

Comment: @JoranBeasley Your answers are both correct, but Marein's is more instructive.

Answer (score 1):

**no this is not possible**. well except something like

```
 x=input("tell me:");print("blah %s"%(x,));
```

but thats not really one line ... it just looks like it

Comment: sorry Joran, I am not sure if i gave you the -1 vote? im a total newbie in stackoverflow (posting side of things) but have researched through it many times! the system says I can only vote after 9 min.

Comment: No need for the second semicolon and the string formatting, just say `print("blah", x)`.